# Unable to run Python script as a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, mqtt, subscribe

I am trying to run an MQTT subscriber script as a subprocess using a base script, but it causes an exception. The script runs fine on its own, but as soon as I try to turn it into a subprocess or run it within a thread, it causes an exception. Can I not run MQTT scripts within separate threads? Or do I have some conflict I'm not aware because I'm new to Python?

The subscribe script

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code: " + str(rc))
    print("Subscribing to topic: ", sub_topic)
    client.subscribe(sub_topic, 2)
    print("Listening...")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("Message Topic =", msg.topic)
    print("Message Payload =", msg.payload.decode())
    check_if_valid_value(json.loads(msg.payload.decode()))
    
def check_if_valid_value(unpackedjson):
    if "accountid" in unpackedjson:
        print("Attribute exists!")
        if unpackedjson["accountid"] == accountId:
            print("Account Id is correct")
            global correct_message_count

def main():
    client = mqtt.Client(client_id)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message

    print("Connecting to broker...")
    try:
        client.connect(broker_address)

        client.loop_forever()
    except:
        print("Interrupted Successfully")
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The base script

```
def main():
    runProvisionTest()

def runProvisionTest():
    print("Starting Provision Test...")
    try:
        p = subprocess.Popen(DeviceProvisionSubscribeTest.main)
    except:
        print("Exception")
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The Stack Trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\christopher\Documents\Python Workspace\BaseTest.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\christopher\Documents\Python Workspace\BaseTest.py", line 11, in main
    runProvisionTest()
  File "c:\Users\christopher\Documents\Python Workspace\BaseTest.py", line 15, in runProvisionTest
    p = subprocess.Popen(DeviceProvisionSubscribeTest.main)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1360, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 565, in list2cmdline
    for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Comment: well don't iterate a function

Comment: That's not how `subprocess` works.  You don't use `subprocess` to run one of your own functions.  You pass it the text of a command line, like `python DeviceProvisionSubscribeTest.py`.

Comment: `p = subprocess.Popen(DeviceProvisionSubscribeTest.main)` You're not using `Popen()` correctly.  The argument to Popen is supposed to be the name of an external program, not a python function object.

Comment: the argument to Popen should be a string or a list of string of the program you want to call identical to how you call it on console

Comment: Thank you guys, that fixed my issue! One of the examples I saw while researching had something similar, so I didn't realize that was wrong